# Creating a directory structure which may partially exist with WinSCP 409 Conflict

Tags: powershell, winscp, winscp-net

Im using WinSCP + Powershell to automatically transfer the build result of Jenkins to our shared server so it can easily be accessed by QA and Dev teams.

WinSCP is required because it can only be transferred via the Webdav protocol. Dont worry about it!!

Lets say the directory on the remote server that i need to create is

```
MyProduct/BuildOutput/bin
```

Now if i perform the below command a with a totally missing folder structure it works perfectly.

```
$session.CreateDirectory("MyProduct/BuildOutput/bin")
```

However if say the "MyProduct/BuildOutput" structure already exists but the "bin" is missing the WinSCP gives a 409 Conflict error.

Is there any way to create a full directory structure that already partially exists without having to write a complex program to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinSCP `CreateDirectory` method does not support the whole directory structure creating. Just single directory. You will have to build the structure on your own. Try this way:

```
    [Array]$dir = 'hello/this/is/test/directory/structure' -split '/'
    $path = [System.String]::Empty
    for ($i=0; $i-lt $dir.Count; $i++){
        if ($i -lt $dir.Count){$path+= $dir[$i] + '/'}
        $session.CreateDirectory($path)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the code start. Problem is i cannot see anyway to change the current remote directory. So CreateDirectory is always being activated from the initial root directory.

Comment: Ok nevermind. This works as long as you only create one extra directory per CreateDirectory command.